# Joomla - Can I add code after # of modules?

Tags: css, loops, joomla

Here's the problem - On my homepage I'm displaying 9 modules at a specified width that float: left. The height is not specified and will vary with each new article that I post to the Section/Category.  There are 3 modules in each row, with the first of the new row set to clear:left.

This works fine with FF3, FF4, Chrome, and IE8 - but IE7 does not appear to be clearing properly.  The modules, each wrapped in a div, seem to be ignoring the clear, and appear almost as though they were just floating.

Hopefully, an image will explain that better than I am able to -

IE7:

[image: ie7]
http://d.pr/N4e4

and on

FF:

[image: ff]
http://d.pr/RZcQ

What I'm wondering is if I can tell Joomla to add a `<div class="clear"></div>` after each set of 3 modules have been displayed?

`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="clear"></div>`
`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="clear"></div>`
`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="module">CONTENT</div>`
`<div class="clear"></div>`

All of that would be a result of the single jdoc:include statement:
`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="articles" style="Articles" />`

Thanks!!

Comment: do you want this to be an automated add of your clear div or a manual one that you insert into the template?

Comment: Well, I believe it has to be automatic, as the one jdoc is loading all 9 modules in that section.  I'm open to any suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in your CSS and the way you are clearing the floats doesn't work with IE7. You probably should implement a solid clear fix in your CSS, here is a really good article on an updated clear fix that works on any modern browser, and IE6/7 too.

http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/

Comment: I guess I should mention that you would need to add "clearfix" to the module class suffix of the each module you want to clear. Depending on how your template is coded, you might need to have a space in front of "clearfix".

Comment: I've tested this out (already had a .clearfix in place) but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.  Currently, the code looks like as above, without the clears every 4th div.  Instead I'm using "clear: left" on the first div in the new row. (Hope that made sense).

Comment: What clearfix code did you try? That may have a bearing on how it worked with IE7. Worst case you can add empty custom HTML modules and apply some CSS to those to make everything line up properly.

Comment: Hmm...  The empty Custom HTML would actually do the trick.  Not the prettiest solution, but it would clear it up.